# Reading all the files in sequence in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am trying to read all the images in the folder in MATLAB using this code

```
flst=dir(str_Expfold);
```

But it shows me output like this. which is not the sequence as i want.
 Can anyone please tell me how can i read all of them in sequence?
[image]

for giving downmark, please explain the reason for that too.

Comment: We can't see the image you uploaded, but I guess they are just image file names. Is this right?

Comment: yes it is the image files starting from depth1,depth2, ...... depth50 originally in the folder.
but when i read the folder in Matlab the sequence is like this
depth1, depth 10, depth11,depth12...depth19,depth2, depth21,...depth29, depth3....

Comment: Then you would have to sort the names as you cannot change the dir output. Take a look at this: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/13978-list-of-files-sorting

Comment: I didn't downvote, but most probably is because the image you uploaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By alphabetical order `depth10` comes before `depth2`.  If at all possible, when creating `string + num` type filenames, use a fixed width numerical part (e.g. `depth01`, `depth02`) - this tends to avoid sorting problems.

If you are stuck with the filenames you have, and know the filename pattern, though, you can not bother using `dir` at all and create your filename list in the correct order in the first place:

```
for n = 1:50
   fname = sprintf('depth%d.png',n);
   % code to read and process images goes here
end
```

Answer (score 3):

From the Matlab forums, the dir command output sorting is not specified, but it seems to be purely alphabetical order (with purely I mean that it does not take into account sorter filenames first). Therefore, you would have to manually sort the names. The following code is taken from [this link](http://mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/13978-list-of-files-sorting) (you probably want to change the file extension):

```
list = dir(fullfile(cd, '*.mat'));
name = {list.name};
str  = sprintf('%s#', name{:});
num  = sscanf(str, 'r_%d.mat#');
[dummy, index] = sort(num);
name = name(index);
```